# Coding a multiracial category in R

Tags: r, r-factor

In my survey dataframe, I have multiple columns corresponding to each race/ethnicity category (e.g., Asian, Black, Hispanic/Latino, White, etc.), with each column coded as 'Y' or 'N'.

I figured out to code a single variable using the following syntax:

```
#Race coding into single variable
dd$Race[dd$Race_Asian=='Y'] <- 'Asian'
dd$Race[dd$Race_Black=='Y'] <- 'Black'
dd$Race[dd$Race_Hispanic=='Y'] <- 'Hispanic/Latinx'
dd$Race[dd$Race_Middle.Eastern=='Y'] <- 'Middle Eastern'
dd$Race[dd$Race_Native.American=='Y'] <- 'Native American'
dd$Race[dd$Race_Native.Hawaiian=='Y'] <- 'Native Hawaiian'
dd$Race[dd$Race_White=='Y'] <- 'White/Caucasian'
dd$Race[dd$Race_Other=='Y'] <- 'Other'

dd$Race <- as.factor(dd$Race)
```

So, how do I code a multiracial category for dd$Race?

Comment: Interesting first question! Just FYI, the language is R. RStudio is just an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment).

Answer (score 0):

*short answer:*  just combine the two statments with '&'

*Long answer: 
An example using* **mtcars:**

I want to know if the car i intend to buy is powerful yet economic, so:
The car i want has 6 or more cylinders & 150+ horsepower & should go more than 18 miles per gallon

I combine the three statments in the [bracets] with '&' and assing the value "nice"

```
mtcars$economic <- ""
mtcars$economic[mtcars$cyl >= 6 & mtcars$hp >= 150 & mtcars$mpg > 18 ] <- "nice"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape your table a bit and then join back.

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(Race_Asian = c("Y","N","N"),
                 Race_Black=c('N',"Y","N"),
                Race_Hispanic = c("N","Y","Y"))
dt[,id:=.I]

# example table
dt
#>    Race_Asian Race_Black Race_Hispanic id
#> 1:          Y          N             N  1
#> 2:          N          Y             Y  2
#> 3:          N          N             Y  3

#reshape solution

ldt <- melt(dt, id.vars = "id",variable.name = "Race_col",value.name = "Response")
ldt
#>    id      Race_col Response
#> 1:  1    Race_Asian        Y
#> 2:  2    Race_Asian        N
#> 3:  3    Race_Asian        N
#> 4:  1    Race_Black        N
#> 5:  2    Race_Black        Y
#> 6:  3    Race_Black        N
#> 7:  1 Race_Hispanic        N
#> 8:  2 Race_Hispanic        Y
#> 9:  3 Race_Hispanic        Y

ldt[,Race1:=fifelse(Response=="Y",sub("Race_","",Race_col),NA_character_)]

ldt[,Race:=paste0(Race1[!is.na(Race1)],collapse = "|"),by=.(id)]

ldt
#>    id      Race_col Response    Race1           Race
#> 1:  1    Race_Asian        Y    Asian          Asian
#> 2:  2    Race_Asian        N     <NA> Black|Hispanic
#> 3:  3    Race_Asian        N     <NA>       Hispanic
#> 4:  1    Race_Black        N     <NA>          Asian
#> 5:  2    Race_Black        Y    Black Black|Hispanic
#> 6:  3    Race_Black        N     <NA>       Hispanic
#> 7:  1 Race_Hispanic        N     <NA>          Asian
#> 8:  2 Race_Hispanic        Y Hispanic Black|Hispanic
#> 9:  3 Race_Hispanic        Y Hispanic       Hispanic

# you can join result back
dt[ldt[,.(Race),by=.(id)],Race:=i.Race,on=.(id)]
dt
#>    Race_Asian Race_Black Race_Hispanic id           Race
#> 1:          Y          N             N  1          Asian
#> 2:          N          Y             Y  2 Black|Hispanic
#> 3:          N          N             Y  3       Hispanic
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: There are no multiracial individuals in your example. What happens if someone is both Black and Hispanic?

Comment: @asac update answer. I didn't understand OP's question untill your comment Thx

Answer (score 0):

### straightforward dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(ID= 1:3,Race_Asian = c("Y","N","N"),
                 Race_Black=c('N',"Y","N"),
                 Race_Hispanic = c("N","Y","Y"))

#    ID Race_Asian Race_Black Race_Hispanic
# 1  1          Y          N             N
# 2  2          N          Y             Y
# 3  3          N          N             Y

df %>%
  pivot_longer(Race_Asian:Race_Hispanic) %>%
  group_by(ID, value) %>% 
  summarise(Race = paste(name, collapse=" & ")) %>% 
  filter(value=="Y") %>% 
  select(-value)


# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   ID [3]
#     ID Race                     
#  <int> <chr>                    
#1     1 Race_Asian               
#2     2 Race_Black & Race_Hispanic
#3     3 Race_Hispanic
```